# PHP-APC error please help

Tags: software-installation, apache2, php

I am trying to install `php-apc` plugin and I am getting an error.

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev libpcre3-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  php5-json

E: Package 'php5-dev' has no installation candidate

sudo pecl install apc

downloading APC-3.1.13.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.13.tgz (171,591 bytes)
.....................................done: 171,591 bytes
55 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Any wonder what is causing this? I tried googling phpize error and else things about this, nothing helped me,.

PHP INFO: http://wolfgaming.eu/web/phpcheck.php

Comment: The first error most likely can be fixed by using `php7-dev`, instead of 5, because you're running php7.  Secondly, are you trying to install APCu?

Comment: "APCu for PHP 7.0 does not support an option for full backwards compatibility with APC. If you require full backwards compatibility with APC and you're using PHP 7.0, you'll also need to install the APCu Backwards Compatibility (apcu-bc) extension."

Comment: phpize is part of php5/7-dev.  Fix that dependency and the command should work, but you may not have any luck getting APC to work with php7.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem you need to install the packages for `php7.0` so your install command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php-dev php-json libpcre3-dev php-apcu
```

Comment: Videonauth, thanks. But still isn't working, it's because my web system isn't accepting apcu but only APC, im trying to set up Caching for HumHub social.

Answer (score 1):

you can fix the problem by installing this pure php apcu compatibility-file:

from https://github.com/SegFaulty/php-apcu-bc

this will emulate the apcu_* function with the apc_* function (and vice versa)

Comment: This was a gift from God and saved me a lot of time trying to configure servers.